# Making DIVIDING program the divide multiple inputs from multiple lists in one time

Tags: python, for-loop, math

I tried to make program that divide multiple variables from list a by multiple variables from list be and I EXCPECTED multivariable dividing outputs

THIS my CODE:

```
def divide(a,b):
    try:
        return a/b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 'Dividing by ZERO is UNDEFINED'

a = [1,7,11,12,23]
b = [23,17,18,0,7]

for A in a:
    print(A)

for B in b:
    print(B) 

print(divide(A,B))
print('END OF PROGRRAM')
```

and THIS is the OUTPUT:

```
1
7
11
12
23
23
17
18
0
7
3.2857142857142856
END OF PROGRRAM
```

Comment: Where does `3.285...` come from?

Comment: You need to loop over `a` and `b`, Python won't do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened here is that you used the last elements of the lists and divided them. This happens because you loop through lists `a` and `b`, binding a value of these lists to `A` and `B` respectively. So by the time you call `divide(A, B)`, these have the value of your last element in the array. Hence it prints `3.2857142857142856` which is `23/7`.

What you could do is a nested for loop if you want to divide every element in a by every element in b:

```py
for A in b:
    for B in b:
        print(divide(a,b))
```

This will loop through all the elements in `a` and divide them by all the elements in `b`, giving you this output:

```py
 for A in a:
...     for B in b:
...         print(divide(A,B))
... 
0.043478260869565216
0.058823529411764705
0.05555555555555555
Dividing by ZERO is UNDEFINED
0.14285714285714285
0.30434782608695654
0.4117647058823529
0.3888888888888889
Dividing by ZERO is UNDEFINED
1.0
0.4782608695652174
0.6470588235294118
0.6111111111111112
Dividing by ZERO is UNDEFINED
1.5714285714285714
0.5217391304347826
0.7058823529411765
0.6666666666666666
Dividing by ZERO is UNDEFINED
1.7142857142857142
1.0
1.3529411764705883
1.2777777777777777
Dividing by ZERO is UNDEFINED
3.2857142857142856
```

If you only want to divide the elements at the same position in the lists, you can use the `zip` function. It makes a list of tuples that you can use for further computation:

```py
for (A, B) in zip(a,b):
...     print(divide(A,B))
... 
0.043478260869565216
0.4117647058823529
0.6111111111111112
Dividing by ZERO is UNDEFINED
3.2857142857142856
```